# Is a nontrivial finite group of order $n$ always isomorphic to a subgroup of $GL_{n-1}(\mathbb{Z})$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, linear-groups

I saw this question on an old qualifying exam:

> Let $G$ be a group of order $n\ge2$. Is such a  group always isomorphic to a subgroup of $GL_{n-1}(\mathbb{Z})$?

A simpler problem would be to show that $G$ is isomorphic to a subgroup of $GL_{n}(\mathbb{Z})$. This seems to follow from that $G$ is isomorphic to a subgroup $H$ of $S_{n}$ and each element of $h$ is associated to a permutation matrix $h' \in GL_{n}(\mathbb{Z})$.  We can consider that the subgroup $H$ which $G$ is isomorphic to is the set of maps $f_{g}: G \rightarrow G$ that multiply on the left by $g$. We then have that every element of $H$ fixes the identity element of $G$ and hence can be viewed as a permutation of $n-1$ elements.

Is there anything more to show from here?

Comment: Is $n$ supposed to be the order of the group?

Comment: Quite right, sorry I will add that.

Comment: Yes you've given the proof basically.

Comment: I've undeleted this to observe that the argument is wrong: left multiplication by an element $g\neq1$ most certainly does not fix the identity element!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You found an injection from $G$ to $GL_n(\mathbb Z)$. Notice that every element in the image preserves the subgroup $H$ of $\mathbb Z^n$ generated by $(1,\dots,1)$, so in this way we get an action of $G$ on $\mathbb Z^n/H$, which is isomorphic to $\mathbb Z^{n-1}$. This action is also injective.

Comment: Or in another formulation: Consider the natural action of $G$ on $\bigoplus_{g\in G, g\ne e}(g-e)\mathbb Z$ where $h\cdot (g-e)=(hg-e)-(h-e)$

Comment: @Mariano Suárez-Alvarez: Yes, indeed, but it looks funny.

Comment: @Mariano Suárez-Alvarez: Just to clarify, the action on $G \times \mathbb{Z}^{n}/H \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}^{n}/H$ is the one where $(g, \bar{x})=\bar{A_{g}x}$. Here $A_{g}$ is the matrix associated to $g$ and $x$ is the representative element of the coset $\bar{x}$. Is this right?

Comment: @user135520, yes.

Comment: What's the precise reason why the map $G\to\text{GL}_{n-1}(\mathbb{Z})$ injective? Is this because the original representation $G\to\text{GL}_n(\mathbb{Z})$ is injective and we just modded out by an invariant subspace? (But what I said doesn't seem rigorous)