# A finite group is isomorphic to a subgroup of $GL_n(\mathbb Z)$

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, group-theory

I'm trying to prove that any finite group $G$ of order $n\ge 2$ is isomorphic to a subgroup of $GL_n(\mathbb Z)$.

My thoughts:

By Cayley, $G$ is isomorphic to a subgroup of $S_n$. Now I need to establish somehow a connection between $S_n$ and $GL_n(\mathbb Z)$. In the case of $n$ small, say $n=2$, $S_3$ acts on $\{e_1,e_2,e_1+e_2\}$, and this action is faithful, which gives an injective homomorphism $GL_2(\mathbb Z)\to S_3$. But a) I guess I need a homomorphism to the other direction (in this case this is an isomorphism, but for larger $n$ it is not I believe) and b) I don't know how to generalize this for larger $n$.

Comment: How about $S_n$ acting on a basis $\{e_1,e_2,...,e_n\}$ for $\mathbb R^n$? And anyway, it's counterproductive to include $0$ in your list, since $0$ is fixed by every element of $GL_n(\mathbb Z)$.

Comment: @LeeMosher This will give an injective homomorphism $\{e_1,\dots,e_n\} \to S_n$, but what is next?

Comment: $S_n$ is isomorphic to the group of permutations of any $n$ element set, such as the set $\{e_1,...,e_n\}$. And any permutation of a basis extends uniquely to an invertible linear transformation.

Comment: Think of this like group actions. Group multiplication just permutes elements, hence the connection to permutation matrices and the general linear group.

Comment: If you want to be particularly terse about it, it suffices to observe that $G$ is a collection of invertible linear maps on the [group algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_ring) $\Bbb Z[G]$, which is isomorphic to $\Bbb Z^n$.

Comment: See [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1341608/is-a-nontrivial-finite-group-of-order-n-always-isomorphic-to-a-subgroup-of-gl?rq=1).

Answer (score 8):

Any finite group embeds into symmetric group (Cayley's theorem), and symmetric group embeds into $GL_n(Z)$ through [permutation matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation_matrix).

Answer (score 0):

Why embed $S_3$ into $GL_2$? An easier way is to embed $\phi:S_3 \to GL_3$, where the function for any permutation $\sigma$ gives rise to the map

$\phi(\sigma)(x_1,x_2,x_3)=(x_{\sigma(1)},x_{\sigma(2)},x_{\sigma(3)}).$

This is a homomorphism, and it has a matrix representation, which can be determined by studying how $\phi(\sigma)$ acts on a basis $e_1,e_2,e_3$. You can do this for any $n \in \mathbb N$.